# RuntimeError: Error creating new content types

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, traceback

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: google, staticfiles, twitter, messages, reflect, allauth, facebook, rest_framework, crispy_forms
  Apply all migrations: account, django_comments, links, sessions, admin, fluent_comments, sites, auth, contenttypes, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 225, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 280, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 82, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
  File "C:\Users\Home\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 78, in get_for_model
    "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

I have tried deleting the db and `makemigrations` and then `migrate`. Same error

Then I tried `migrate contenttypes` before `migrate`. No change in the traceback.

What's wrong?

I'm using django==1.8

Comment: Try `python manage.py migrate contenttypes --fake`.

Comment: `ContentType.name` field has been deprecated in Django 1.8.  Another option which you can try to remove the column `name` ie. `ALTER TABLE django_content_type DROP COLUMN name`.

Comment: No change in traceback

Comment: Check this [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24075) and [Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/DlRQOdsJL6o/IbN_1Cjjyz8J) regarding this issue.

Comment: That ticket is for django==1.7. I never used 1.7
Groups didn't help much.   Thank you, though @RahulGupta

Comment: @StackExchange - How did you solve the problem? I am facing the same. And nothing is helping me

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same error message. In my case it was after I injected additional fields into the Django group model. Maybe you do something similiar. The problem is that the auth migration created for the modified Group model is in the pip package folder of Django.

I found it in:

```
<my_env_folder>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0007_auto_20151118_1635.py
```

You could add it as dependency to the failing migration:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0007_auto_20151118_1635'),
    ('accounts', '0001_admin_user'),
]
```

But it would fail when re-building the env from scratch. So this is not a solution :-/.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was related with https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25100 bug. For some reason, `contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name` migration was not executed, bet marked as executed. To fix that, I just removed `name` field manually using this query:

```
alter table django_content_type drop column name;
```

After that, migrations started to work.